# I want to create an object of objects input with the results from looping an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I want to construct a JSON object from the result obtained by iterating through the array below.

Here is the array list : Input

```
var input = [
  {
    bio: "Test",
    id: 2,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
    user: 2
  }, 
  {
    
    bio: "Test2",
    id: 3,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png",
    user: 2
  } 
]

I want something like the below:
```

Expected output:

```
   {
  "Test": {
    bio: "Test",
    id: 2,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
    },
  "TestTwo": {
     bio: "TestTwo",
    id: 3,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/mediafile/default.jpg",
   }
}
```

I am able to get array of objects but not the exact format that I want. Need to call ajax with the same output.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question from 45 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928375/i-want-to-send-a-json-with-results-from-looping-array)? We asked you to add your code to your question - something you didn't do then, and haven't done now. You didn't answer any questions, and clearly didn't read the help documentation.

Comment: @Andy not comfortable with sharing the original data and hence shared the sample code which resembles the original code. Deleted the earlier question.  Also, I have modified a little since the question posted earlier might have misunderstood by people who replied.

Comment: _The code you've attempted to solve the problem_, not the data structures.

Comment: you can use `reduce` method to create `object` from array of object.

Comment: Remember to convert the object into JSON by using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you; if you're not making any effort to solve your own problem this looks like a bad faith effort to benefit from the work of others.

Comment: @David thanks for the suggestion. I am learning and I never asked someone to do my job. I asked for sincere help as I wasn't able to  figure out. Don't know why is this taken offensively.

Comment: Please see Andy's first comment: "*We asked you to add your code to your question - something you didn't do then, and haven't done now. You didn't answer any questions, and clearly didn't read the help documentation.*" If you're not attempting to write a solution, even with pseudo-code to demonstrate an understanding of your problem, and not answering requests for clarification then I'm afraid it undermines your stated "learning" and "[asking] for help." Unfortunately we have rather high expectations and standards for questions here, and we expect you to measure up to those standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = [
  {
    bio: "Test",
    id: 2,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
    user: 2
  }, 
  {
    
    bio: "Test2",
    id: 3,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png",
    user: 2
  } 
];

const final = input.reduce((res, obj) => {
  res[obj.bio] = obj;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928375/i-want-to-send-a-json-with-results-from-looping-array) you asked to do the opposite, and my answer was:
Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and add user property with value 2:

```js
const input = {
  Test: {
    bio: "Test",
    id: 2,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
  },
  TestTwo: {
    bio: "TestTwo",
    id: 3,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/mediafile/default.jpg",
  },
};
const objs = Object.values(input);
for (let obj of objs) {
    obj.user = 2
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(objs, null, 4))
```

```js
/*
[
    {
        "bio": "Test",
        "id": 2,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
        "user": 2
    },
    {
        "bio": "TestTwo",
        "id": 3,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/mediafile/default.jpg",
        "user": 2
    }
]
 */
```

Other ways to add property user:
You could use Use `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
objs = objs.map(obj => ({ ...obj, user: 2 }))
```

or use with more readable with [object assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
objs = objs.map(obj => {
  const userPropsObj = {
    user: 2
  };
  return Object.assign(obj, userPropsObj);
});
```

---

The answer to this question which tend to return back to the initial input(object) instead of an array:
you could iterate over the array and *delete `user` property* we add and assign each object with `bio` as the key.

```js
const input = [
  {
    bio: "Test",
    id: 2,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.jpg",
    user: 2
  }, 
  {
    
    bio: "Test2",
    id: 3,
    image: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png",
    user: 2
  } 
];
const output = {};
for (let obj of input) {
    delete obj.user;
    output[obj.bio] = obj;
}
console.log(output)
```

*PS: Please, Don't delete the question as you did before because you delete the answers we did too, And maybe answers help someone else!*

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = input.reduce((result, item) => { result[item.bio] = item;
return result;
}, {});
```

`reduce` is a higher-order function it takes a method as an argument that method contains the result and items in my example; it iterates over each item in the array and assigns the whole object value to the key we created which is `item.bio` accumulating all these keys will results in one object with the keys and values as needed.